# How do I set a static class property in a PHP extension class?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I am writing a PHP extension in C that includes PHP classes defined in C. I would like to set a static property on one of the classes. In particular, I would like to do in C the equivalent of

```
class Example{
  public static $member;
}

Example::member = new Example();
```

I can't use the `REGISTER_*_CONSTANT` macros to do this because the value needs to be an object. I checked the official documentation, but the section about classes is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot actually register a static property, instead you just have to update it, and have PHP do the registering for you.

http://php.undmedlibrary.org/manual/en/zend-api.zend-update-static-property.php

```
// int zend_update_static_property         ( zend_class_entry* $scope, char* $name, int $name_length, zval* $value,        magic $TSRMLS_DC )
int prop_set = zend_update_static_property ( my_example_class_entry,   "member",    7,                my_instance          TSRMLS_CC);
```

Comment: This looks like the right function, but I'm having trouble verifying that it does what I want because I wanted to call it in `PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION`, but it looks like something (probably `executor_globals`) is not yet initialized by that time.

Answer (score 1):

In my specific case, my class wrapped a C struct, so I am apparently unable to initialize it at module initialization. I took the next best option, which was to declare a static method that returned a statically declared instance. I did this by putting the line

```
PHP_ME(Example, member, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC|ZEND_ACC_STATIC)
```

in my `example_methods` array, by globally declaring `zval *php_example_static_member` in my header file, and by writing the function as

```
PHP_METHOD(Example, member){
  if(php_example_static_member == NULL){
    php_example_static_member = create_example_instance(); //However the new instance is created
  }
  RETURN_ZVAL(php_example_static_member, false, false);
}
```